# Could there be a sum of polynomials for the nth prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, summation-method

All I am wondering is if there could be a formula of the following form for the nth prime number:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(i,n)$$

where f(i,n) is a series of terms only featuring a constant and integer powers of n and i.

Comment: Any such formula could be written as $F(n)$ for some polynomial $F$. But then the rate of growth of $F$ would be either linear or at least quadratic, whereas the $n$th prime grows like $n\log n$.

Comment: To add, it is proven that there is no polynomial with one variable which always generates prime number.

Comment: Wojowu, are you sure that it can be written as $F(n)$? For example, for n=0 you can have $2n^0$, whereas for n=1 you can have $7n^0 + 3n^1 + 8n^2$.

Comment: @MånsNilsson What is your $f(i,n)$?

Comment: @Wojowu It's a series of terms only featuring a constant, n and/or i.

Comment: What do you mean by "series" and "terms"?

Comment: Terms only feature integer powers of i and n and a constant.

Comment: i as the imaginary number whose square is -1 or just another variable?

Comment: @AlessaWade Just another variable. That's why it says $f(i,n)$ instead of $f(n)$. You can also see from $i=0$ that the iteration is done over $i$.

Comment: I was just making sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By grouping terms with equal degrees in $i$, we can write
$$f(i,n)=f_d(n)i^d+f_{d-1}(n)i^{d-1}+\dots+f_1(n)i+f_0(n)$$
for $f_k(n)$ some polynomials in $n$. Summing this over $i$ gives
$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(i,n)=\sum_{k=0}^d f_k(n)\sum_{i=0}^n i^k$$.
The sum of $k$-th powers of numbers from $0$ to $n$ can be written as a polynomial $P_k(n)$, so the expression in your question is a polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^d f_k(n)P_k(n)$. As I mention in a comment, this polynomial grows either linearly or at least quadratically, which means that this cannot be an expression for the $n$-th prime, since that grows line $n\log n$.